# jcifs.smb.SmbException: The parameter is incorrect error- Login form not for entering credential+NTLMv1 request

Tags: java, single-sign-on, jcifs

My web application is **interanet** based.It is working fine in **interanet** environment.Showing login/without login showing and user is able to login in application because it is using windows credentials.

**But error in below scenaria:-**
We are using **good.com** to browse same interanet application on mobile phones or tablet.It is not working showing error.This application is using jcifs for single sign on..
Error..

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

jcifs.smb.SmbException: The parameter is incorrect.

```
    jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:542)

    jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:644)

    jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:307)

    jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:235)

    jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:161)

    jcifs.smb.SmbSession.logon(SmbSession.java:171)

    jcifs.smb.SmbSession.logon(SmbSession.java:164)

    jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.negotiate(NtlmHttpFilter.java:189)

    jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.doFilter(NtlmHttpFilter.java:121)

    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)

    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.24 logs.

Thanks
[Devloper](http://www.careergoal.in)

Comment: After changing the Group policy "Networkaccess: lan-manager authentication level" to respond to NTLMv1 request, we are able to access on desktop. Because here we can change windows/system setting. But how it will respond to extenal environment either we have to programmatically set access..this is still question?

Comment: As per documentation we find good.com not supports NTLM v1 request...So we have to move to NTLM v 2 request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved above problem for Good.com by using javascript url redirect on the basis of mobile and system detection.
Both redirected to seprate page.So this solution solved problem.

Because you cant change old application logic to change single sign in security.

Thanks